# Hebrew filenames in the URL

Tags: url

We have a CMS that enables users to upload images and flashes to their site.
Sometimes the filenames are in Hebrew.
In our development server there is no problem, but in our production server we get a 404 error when the filename ends with [Hebrew characters.](http://light.ort.org.il/SiteHTML/LeaOnRuby/Flash/93708405-cd7b-41d8-a2b8-4b17b750b646)
I tried comparing the sites in the IIS, but I'm not sure what to even look for, so I'd be very happy to get pointers as to what might be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that the problem is caused by a security tool installed on the server.

Comment: Please add some details about the name/version of the security tool and the way you tracked and resolved that problem, thank you !

Comment: @Shadok, I would like to, but this was 2 years ago and I don't remember what the tool was, and I don't know how the tracking and resolving was done - it wasn't me who did it.

Comment: Ok, at least we know we'll never know ^^ Thank you for your answer anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a normalisation/high-bit problem, can you describe your environment? What is hosting your CMS application, assuming that your DEV and PROD servers are configured the same, do you have any proxy's which are blocking high-bit characters?